# Google ReCaptcha 2 auto submit

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

My users will see a google repcatcha2 (nocaptcha) in a web page. When they solve the captcha (put the tick in the box) the form should be automatically submit.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it.
In [this post](https://webscraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/) I've explained how to insert reCaptcha into a site and to code javascript to verify user and site.

1. Add a name to your form with reCaptcha:  `<form method="post" name="myform">`
2. Add `document.myform.submit();` code for submitting of the form upon the site verification success event:

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>    
     var onReturnCallback = function(response) { 
       var url='proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  
       $.ajax({ 'url' : url, 
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: { response: response},
                  success: function( data  ) {  
                       var res = data.success.toString(); 
                       if (res)
                          { document.myform.submit(); }    
                   }  // end success 
              });  // end $.ajax

     };  // end onReturnCallback
   </script>
   ```