# Detect/listen for google recaptcha submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

I've tried searching for this online but found nothing.

What I need is to check when the user submits the recaptcha and send the form *from* it (i.g. also acting as a submission button). **I'm aware google's recaptcha is iframed** so I was wondering how exactly this could be done:

1. Actually listen to the submission event locally using javascript and submit the form
2. Listen for the submission in my php server and afterwards communicate conclusion of the request to my user

I'm hoping that 1 is actually possible because the second one would be an immense pain to the buttocks. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this, preferably by method 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> listen to the submission event locally using javascript and submit the form

You want to listen the reCaptcha submission and send the form. Then see my answer to the similar question: [ReCaptcha v2.0 auto submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626433/1230477)

### Important

Important thing is that you need to submit form **only if the google server verification is successful**. And the code in the answer works this out:

```
success: function( data  ) {  
                var res = data.success.toString(); 
                if (res)
                   { document.myform.submit(); }    
            }  // end success
```

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a function to verify the captcha. You need to verify it prior to allowing your form to submit. Please see their documentation for further details: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

My setup is something like this:
    `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>`

```
var RC2KEY = 'sitekey';
function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
        /* do something */
    }
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    grecaptcha.render('id', {
        'sitekey': RC2KEY,
        'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
        'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}
```